# How can I navigate from custom class to UIViewController in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift4

I have a ViewController which have a button, it calls some method in MyClass.swift. I'm trying to navigate from MyClass.swift to UIViewController MainViewController when I press that button. I implemented this method and I get "navigating..." in the log but nothing happen.

```
class Myclass {
// some code ...
func someFunc() {

    // some code ...
    navigateToMainViewController()

}

func navigateToMainViewController() {
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.storyboard
    if let myMVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") {
        print("navigating....")
        let navController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
        navController?.pushViewController(myMVC, animated: true)
    }else {
        print("Something wrong..")
    }
}

// some code ...
}
```

Thank your for your help.

Comment: From where are you calling `someFunc()`?

Comment: From a Button in the UIViewController

Comment: Have a reference to the ViewController in which you use the object of MyClass. Then use a delegate to call the navigation method which you must write in your ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Change your navigation Function and add a parameter of viewController to it, and take a variable in myClass of type **UIViewController**:

```
var viewController: UIViewController!


func someFunc(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
    self.viewController = viewController
    self.navigateToMainViewController()
}

func navigateToMainViewController() {
  let storyboard: UIStoryboard? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.storyboard
  if let myMVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") {
      print("navigating....")

      self.viewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(myMVC, animated: true)
  }else {
      print("Something wrong..")
  }
}
```

Then From viewController, Call **someFunc()** with instance of ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
          myClassObject.someFunc(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I need the someFunc() because it returns a callback which I test on it to call the navigation

Comment: @K.Walid Updated the answer!